# A Striking Resemblance (no.2)

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

I didn’t explain how the first one worked as to prevent it from being to easy; the way these riddles work is that I supply as many synonyms to a word as possible (within reason) to narrow down your search for a single word.

> I feel lazy tonight, laidback but alright, eating some dinner fed on a dime.
>
> So while I’m relaxed, I watch people act, unhurried while they solve a crime.
>
> My day was quite slow, quite idle you know,  with sluggish workers in line.
>
> It seemed apathetic, indolent like traffic, as the clock shows lethargic time.
>
> As the night goes by, I wonder why, I feel sluggish and listless but fine.

### What is the word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this

> SLOTH?

The synonyms are:

I feel lazy tonight, laidback but alright, eating some dinner fed on a dime.

> Lazy and laidback are sloth.

So while I’m relaxed, I watch people act, unhurried while they solve a crime.

> Relaxed and unhurried.

My day was quite slow, quite idle you know, with sluggish workers in line.

> Quite slow, idle, sluggish

It seemed apathetic, indolent like traffic, as the clock shows lethargic time.

> Apathetic, indolent, lethargic

As the night goes by, I wonder why, I feel sluggish and listless but fine.

> Sluggish, listless